# MadelineProto: how listen subscribe event?

Tags: php, telegram

i'm writing telegram bot-administrator and using this [package](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto)
have this code

```
$settings = new Settings();
$appInfo = new Settings\AppInfo();
$appInfo->setApiHash(config('telegram.app.app_info.api_hash'))
->setApiId(config('telegram.app.app_info.api_id'));
$settings->setAppInfo($appInfo);
$api = new API(time(), $settings);
$api->botLogin(env('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'));
$api->startAndLoop(NewSubscriberListener::class);

class NewSubscriberListener extends EventHandler
{
    public function onUpdateNewChannelMessage(array $update)
    {
        print_r(__METHOD__);
        yield print_r($update);
    }
    public function onUpdateChatParticipants(array $update)
    {
        print_r(__METHOD__);
        yield print_r($update);
    }
}
```

when i write message into chat - i listen him, but where new user subscribe - nothing

tell me please where my mistake ? or this not possible?

Comment: https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/UPDATES.html only shows methods onUpdateNewChannelMessage and onUpdateNewMessage, and the whole thing is titled "Handling updates (new messages)" - so where did you find `onUpdateChatParticipants`?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for [updateChannelParticipant](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/constructors/updateChannelParticipant.html) (supergroups), [updateChatParticipantAdd](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/constructors/updateChatParticipantAdd.html) (groups).